# how to notify javascript that something happened in database

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-messaging

Now I'm using google cloud messaging, Doing somekind of chatting room between two persons, Now  I need to notify my html Code that the user B has just submitted a new message and saved to the database so User A at once is able to see this message without refreshing the page

is there a function doing that or some tool ??

Note : I'm not Javascript Expert and it's The First time to do Some Auto Response Program

I've Followed the instructions found in this page, till the part before doing any thing to the android ==> http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Read up on polling a server

Comment: The combination of `node.js` and `websocket` can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, its pretty simple to set up `node.js` server with `socket.io` using in the [front and back](http://socket.io/) – the first page itself can get you started.

For more complex applications there's also Firebase, which I have no experience with yet but I'm definitely going to give it a try.

Architecture wise, I'd always avoid keeping an eye on the database for changes. I'd have the backend logic that interprets the incoming changes and updates the clients that are listening, and then updates the database. Polling isn't the way to go, for anything scalable.

Comment: u mean polling will take un-needed time to check whether the database is changed or not ?

and also i don't know any thing about socket ... is this the only way ??

Comment: @user3179928 no of course this isn't the only way – polling is indeed the _simpler_ solution, albeit ugly. Polling is very inefficient, instead of the client just waiting to hear from the server if something has changed, you have a client constantly querying the server to see if something has changed. So you make unnecessary network transfers, and on your server you constantly cause the server to query for change instead of _letting the change happen first_ if that makes sense.

Comment: so the alternative way is to make the server send a notification when the database is changed instead of polling the server every 1 sec ... now the problem that i'm beginner at this is there any tutorial or steps which i can follow to do this task ... hint : i'm really beginner at this

Comment: @user3179928 just a bit of googling: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNKNYLv2BpQ this can get you up and running! There's no better way to learn new stuff than by building something with it!

Comment: One More Question , I Seem To Be stupid but, What is the Usage of Google Messaging Cloud in the Link Which i've refereed to in the post ??

Comment: I think google cloud messaging can keep you from writing a backend that can _inform_ javascript of changes. So on the front end side, you'll just need to listen for new messages and let Google handle the backend. I think this might help you a bit https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/pubsub_messaging.